# Puppet output to agent without notify

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise

Given the following example:

```
[root@puppet ~]# cat notify_test.pp
define test (
  Boolean $condition = false,
) {

  if $condition {
    notify { "Debug Output of Test[${title}]": }
  }
}

$test_resource_name_a = 'A'
test { $test_resource_name_a: 
  condition => true,
}

$test_resource_name_b = 'B'
test { $test_resource_name_b: }



exec { 'TestExec':
  refreshonly => true,
  command     => '/usr/bin/echo "Mock Service Refresh"',
  logoutput   => true,
  subscribe   => Test[$test_resource_name_a, $test_resource_name_b],
}
```

Which should only print something to the agent but appearently refreshes all subscribing resources becaus of resource containment (see https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/4.10/lang_containment.html). Unwanted result:

```
[root@puppet ~]# puppet apply notify_test.pp
Notice: Compiled catalog for puppet in environment production in 0.10 seconds
Notice: Debug Output of Test[A]
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Test[A]/Notify[Debug Output of Test[A]]/message: defined 'message' as 'Debug Output of Test[A]'
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Exec[TestExec]/returns: Mock Service Refresh
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Exec[TestExec]: Triggered 'refresh' from 1 events
Notice: Applied catalog in 1.53 seconds
```

So whenever the condition is met (e.g. my custom function which uses an HTTP Client to get data from REST APIs which I use is my manifests but dont have real impact on the catalog compilation) all subscribers (e.g. services) would restart every 30 minutes.

This behaviour is unacceptable, so how can I print something to the puppet agent (`puppet agent -t`) without notifying/refreshing auto-contained resources?

Answer (score 2):

This is a limitation inherent in modeling `Notify` as a resource.  By definition and design, applying a resource does nothing if that resource is initially in sync with the target system.  In order that `Notify` resources do anything (i.e. emit their message), they are always initially out of sync, and emitting their message brings them into sync.  You can conceptualize that as a transition from "not printed" to "printed", if you like.

But that means that from Puppet's perspective, every `Notify` resource is changed every time it is applied.  That generates an event, which is propagated to the `Notify`'s container and onward.

> This behaviour is unacceptable, so how can I print something to the
>   puppet agent (`puppet agent -t`) without notifying/refreshing
>   auto-contained resources?

If you must have the messages in the *agent*'s log (as opposed to the master's) then your options are limited.  In fact, the best I can come up with is to write a custom resource type and provider that is always in sync, yet emits messages into the log anyway.  I tested using an `Exec` with an `unless` parameter that emits the message, but Puppet does not seem to print the output of the `unless` command.  Certainly, `Notify` is right out.

If it would be sufficient to emit the message into the *master*'s log, then there is a set of functions for that purpose.  Among them, [notice()](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/function.html#notice), [info()](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/function.html#info), and [debug()](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/function.html#debug) seem the most likely for your purpose.

**Side note**: the phrase "auto-contained resources" suggests that there is another kind.  Before Puppet 6 you could declare resources at top scope, and those are contained only by the catalog itself, which does not propagate events to anything else.  But every resource declared inside a container -- class or defined type -- is contained by that container.  That's always seemed very natural to me.  Usually the thing that trips people up about containment is that *classes* are only contained when you explicitly make it so.  There are good reasons for that, but I won't go into them here.